# Firebase SAML Auth with Azure AD "auth/invalid-credential" after successfull login

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, firebase-authentication, saml, google-identity

I've a Firebase project with Authentication and also SAML works without any problem.
I now try to configure a second Firebase project with the same settings and the same SAML login.
I configured the SAML identiy provider in the GCP Identity Platform same as in the old project and try to login with the code from the docs:

```
 const auth = getAuth();
    let provider = new SAMLAuthProvider('saml.' + providerId);
    return signInWithPopup(auth, provider)
      .then((result) => {
        // User is signed in.
        console.log("SAML Result: " + JSON.stringify(result))
        return
        // Provider data available in result.additionalUserInfo.profile,
        // or from the user's ID token obtained from result.user.getIdToken()
        // as an object in the firebase.sign_in_attributes custom claim.
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        // Handle error.
        console.log("SAML error: " + JSON.stringify(error))
      });
```

but now I'm getting always the error

```
https://identitytoolkit.googleapis.com/v1/accounts:signInWithIdp?key=.... 400
```

Followed with the Firebase error:

```
{"code":"auth/invalid-credential","customData":{"appName":"[DEFAULT]"},"name":"FirebaseError"}
```

`invalid-credential` sounds a bit weird, because the SAML auth (with Azure AD) was fine.

Do I've missed some config in the GCP? Or maybe in the Firebase project?
In the old (working) project I configured nothing special. I

Comment: Based on your error, the credential used to authenticate the Admin SDKs cannot be used to perform the desired action. Have you tried [initializing the SDK](https://firebase.google.com/docs/admin/setup#initialize-sdk) first? You can check the full details of the error through this [link](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/errors#:~:text=auth/invalid%2Dcredential).

Comment: Thanks for looking after that. Do I need the Admin SDK in a normal ionic/angular project (in the browser / no server)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't know the reason, but had to delete the Azure AD app for this service and made a new one with the same entity. Works now ;-)